# Is sinus scalable?

Tags: assembly, numbers, fpu, x87

By sinus I mean here c stdlib sin() / fpu assembl;y fsin.

I can give to this sinus argument with about 16 decimal
digits presision or more, for example sin(1.1e-14); 
sin(1.2e-14) then get results,

sinus is almost linear on such small deltas but despite of
it can be calculated with same 16 digits precisions too,
Is it exacltly calculated on such small deltas too?

(I ask about it becouse it seemed somewhat unusual for me for a while 
to calc it for such far precision in both argument and especially output 
value, so I wonder if it is not cut down or something)

Comment: in the floating-point world, nothing is calculated _exactly_. well, almost nothing.

Comment: I do not mean exactly I meant 'fully'

Comment: FYI, in English the correct term is "sine" (or "sine function").

Comment: Igor, can you explain the linguistic logic of saying sine rather than sinus? sinus is the latin term, and used in most european languages. perhaps Sine is informal?

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series of sin(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - ...

Any number 0 > *x* > 1 is represented in base 10 as

x = a*10^-n,  where 1<=a<10    e.g. x=0.003 = 3*10^-3
 x^3 = a^3 * 10^-3n

then the magnitude of the next term is about b*10^-3n (ignoring the factorial).
As *n* grows (or *x* approaches zero) the next terms start to vanish pretty fast.

for x=0.003 the few first terms are

```
   0.003000000000000000 = 10^-3 * 3000000000000000  <-- x
 - 0,000000004500000000 = 10^-3 * 0000004500000000  <-- x^3/3!
 + 0,000000000000002025 = 10^-3 * 0000000000002025  <-- x^5/5!
 ----------------------   -----------------------------
 = 0.002999995500002025 = 10^-3 * 2999995500002025
```

There are 16 digits ignoring the leading zeroes and the 4th term x^7/7! doesn't affect any more the result. When x goes even smaller, next the x^5/5! term can't be added to the result and finally the x^3/3! term can't be added (or subtracted). Only the term x can be represented with 16 digit accuracy.

sin(x) = x only for x=0. exactly. Everything else is approximation.
Even sin(pi/2)=1 is approximation in math libraries, as the argument pi/2 can't be represented as a floating point number.

Comment: so, it is just not fully exact in full "long double in - long double out " domain? or it is?

Comment: Taking a look on the Taylorseries above you can see you can make the approximation as exact as you want. So its also possible to find a best approximation in terms of endless precision number system. It simply depends of the kind of implementation of the `sin` function.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Can you please explain more about the second and third equations? I dont see the steps to end there from the Taylor series. What is `a` and what is `n`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: x=(1+a)*2^n (or -n) is one way to generalize any number x. If the x represented in base 2 is small enough, the second and third parts of the infinite Taylor series go so small compared to the mantissa _a_ of the floating point number, that they just can be represented in 64, 128 or even 2000 bit floating point numbers. With finite floating point system there is eventually such small number, that all x<epsilon, sin(x) must be represented as x.

Comment: The taylor series is the taylor series. I dont understand why C fsin would be based on the taylor series, it would be much innacurate? can you assert why fsin is based on such an inaccurate approximation, when it is intended for 32bit processors?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, it starts failing when greater than 9e18 and less than 9e-18 for positive numbers. This is a limitation of the CPU.

Details can be read on http://www.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253665.pdf under 8.1.3.2 Condition Code Flags specifying the limit of FSIN and friends.

Comment: sounds more referenced that the taylor series answer.

Comment: Yes, but the _analysis_ in the other answer (and the upvoted comment underneath) actually prove why.